# Collection exists, but Mongoose query returns empty set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB install with a database called `Collector` which contains a collection named `Msg`. 
When I view it with the `mongo` shell I get 65 results.

However, when querying MongoDB using the Mongoose code below I get an empty set:

```
var Msg = mongoose.model('Msg', {
    process: String
    // omitted fields
});

server.use(express.static('./client')); // Serve the client

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
               "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

// Return to the client a JSON object containing *ALL* msgs
server.get('/msgs', function(req, res) {
    Msg.find().exec(function(err, msgs) {
        log(`err: ${err}`);
        log(`/msgs => Found ${msgs.length} msgs`);
        res.json(msgs);
    });
});
```

Everything seems ok, but it doesn't work: visiting `localhost:3000/msgs` yields an empty result object. So what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in the name of the collection: I had named it `Msg` while apparently Mongo looks in `Msgs` by default if the model name is `Msg`.  The solution here is to add a 3rd arg to the Model call:

```
var Msg = mongoose.model('Msg', {
    process: String
    // omitted fields
}, 'Msg'); // <-- collection name
```